# Where shall I place the function in the pipeline file?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm working on a Jenkins shared library.

My plan is to be able to decrease the number of lines in each Jenkinsfile to the minimum.

I want to be able to do something like:

`buildProduct()` and that it will issue a pipeline build which resides in the shared library.

My standardPipeline.groovy file looks like so:

```
import com.company.utils.pipelineFunctions;
import com.company.utils.Git;

def ris = new pipelineFunctions()

def run_in_stage(String stage_name, Closure command){
    ris.run_in_stage(stage_name, command, emailadd)
}

 def call(body) {

        def config = [:]
        body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
        body.delegate = config
        body()

        node {
            // Clean workspace before doing anything
            deleteDir()


            try {
                def ris = new pipelineFunctions()
                //run_in_stage('Clone', {
                run_in_stage('Clone', {
                    checkout scm
                })

                stage ('Build') {
                    sh "echo 'building ${config.projectName} ...'"
                }
                stage ('Tests') {
                    parallel 'static': {
                        sh "echo 'shell scripts to run static tests...'"
                    },
                    'unit': {
                        sh "echo 'shell scripts to run unit tests...'"
                    },
                    'integration': {
                        sh "echo 'shell scripts to run integration tests...'"
                    }
                }
                stage ('Deploy') {
                    sh "echo 'deploying to server ${config.serverDomain}...'"
                    sh "echo Itai ganot"
                }
            } catch (err) {
                currentBuild.result = 'FAILED'
                throw err
            }
        }
    }
```

The pipelineFunctions.groovy file looks like so:

```
package com.company.utils;
import com.company.utils.Git;

def run_in_stage(String stage_name, Closure command, String sendTo){

    def gitTool = new Git()

    String ulink = gitTool.getCommitter()
    String jlink = "(<${env.BUILD_URL}|Open>)"

  println "============================================================"
  stage (stage_name) {
      try {
          command()
          if (currentBuild.result == 'FAILURE') {
              error "Build failed, see log for further details."
          }
          println "============================================================"
      } catch (Exception ex) {
          def except = "${ex}"
          String emailadd = ulink+'@company.com'
          if (currentBuild.result == null) {
            currentBuild.result = "FAILURE" }
                        this.notifyStatus(stage_name, currentBuild.result, except)
          echo "Pipeline failed at stage: ${stage_name}"
          throw ex
      }
  }
}

return this;
```

When I run the build it fails with the following error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: ris for class: groovy.lang.Binding
```

I'm trying to understand where shall I place the run_in_stage function definition because where ever I put it, it causes the build to fail.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In `standardPipeline.groovy`, you need to declare `ris` inside the `run_in_stage` method to be able to use it there. E.g.:

```
import com.company.utils.pipelineFunctions;
import com.company.utils.Git;

// This instance may no longer be necessary, not sure if it's used outside run_in_stage
def ris = new pipelineFunctions()

def run_in_stage(String stage_name, Closure command){
    def ris = new pipelineFunctions()
    String emailadd = 'me@company.com' // edit: for 3rd param
    ris.run_in_stage(stage_name, command, emailadd)
}
```

---

**Edit:** I ran this after the report of an unspecified error in the comment, and I've updated the above with an example of what I needed to add.

The above worked fine for me (after removing some other stuff that was unavailable or irrelevant), when called from the following pipeline script:

```
// just loading above shared library explicitly
@Library('jenkins-pipeline-library-test') _

StandardPipeline {
    println 'something'
}
```

**Edit 2:** Here's an example of what the shared library project structure should be, in case there has been any confusion about where each of the files should be placed: https://github.com/grdryn/jenkins-pipeline-library-test

Comment: I still get an error on the "def ris = new pipelineFunctions()" within the run_in_stage function

Comment: @ItaiGanot I've recreated the above and run it. The only error I got was very explicit: `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: emailadd for class: StandardPipeline`. I've added the fix for that above (just declared something called `emailadd` in the scope). Is this the error that you encountered, or was it something else?